# BarCodeScanner doesn't work in Ionic 6 and Cordova in Android device

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to use BarCodeScanner in Ionic 6 but when I call the function to open the camera and scan, I get the message **Scan is already in progress**. It doesn't open the camera or do anything. I don't understand why this is happening, if someone could help me, I would be very grateful. Attached is my code:

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

constructor(
  private menuCtrl:MenuController,
  private apiService: ApiService,
  private modalCtrl: ModalController,
  private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner
) { } 
 
public scan(){
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
      this.scannedData = barcodeData;

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }
```

And app.module.ts:

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Stripe,
    Camera,
    BarcodeScanner,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner
```

```
then :

   import { BarcodeScanner }from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx';
    
   constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) { }
   ...

   this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
   console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
   }).catch(err => {
   console.log('Error', err);
   });
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it didn't work either. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use that fork

https://github.com/shekhartupe/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

I have not tried, but I see this change in [www/barcodescanner.js](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/compare/master...shekhartupe:master), on line 108 and 111 by removing the condition check if (scanInProgress) { }.

See below

```js
/*if (scanInProgress) {
   errorCallback('Scan is already in progress');
   return;
 }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was migrate to capacitor, I used this guide: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor.
I hope this can help you.

More details here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/861#issuecomment-606464923